# Loading related entities in Entity Framework: how to filter which entities should be loaded?

Tags: entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework model with one-to-many relationships: `Client` entity could have many `Orders`.

I want to load `Client` entity and all `Orders` made by the client except ones that are marked as `Obsolete` in my database.

Unfortunately, I can't use `Orders.Load()` because it loads all orders and doesn't accept any predicate, so I can't just write `client.Orders.Load(o => !o.Obsolete)`.

So, how could I load only up-to-date orders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use with Projection:

```
var client = context.Client.Select(c => new 
    { 
        Client = c, 
        Orders = c.Orders.Where(o => !o.Obsolete)
    });
```